# Tkinter: AttributeError: type object '' has no attribute 'self' while searching to avoid circular import error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to avoid a circular import error in my script, but I'm getting this error  `AttributeError: type object 'LoginInfo' has no attribute 'self'` . This is my code split in three file:
**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import login_page

class Main(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.login_page = login_page.LoginInfo(self)
    self.login_page.pack(fill="both", expand='True')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    Main(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**login_page.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import page_one

class LoginInfo(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

      self.login_frame = tk.Frame(self)
      self.login_frame.pack()

      self.username_label = tk.Label(self.login_frame, text='Username:')
      self.username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

      self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_frame)
      self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

      self.login_button = tk.Button(self.login_frame, text='Login', command=self.login)
      self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)

  def login(self):
     self.page_one = page_one.PageOne(self)
     self.page_one.pack(fill="both", expand='True')

     self.login_frame.destroy()
     self.login_frame.pack_forget()
```

**page_one.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import login_page

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)                                                              

       self.info()

   def info(self):
       print(login_page.self.username_entry.get())
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in this line `print(login_page.self.username_entry.get())`  but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try removing self from print(login_page.self.username_entry.get())

Comment: at this point you would just make a method of whatever class login_page is that returns whatever is in the username_entry box. E.g. make a method 
get_username_entry():
      return self.username_entry.get()

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: And yes, these imports are circular.  `login_page.py` imports `page_one.py`, and vice versa.  You can't do that.

Comment: The instance of `LoginInfo` is passed as the parent of instance of `PageOne`, so you can use `self.master.username_entry.get()` instead. Then you don't need to import `login_page` inside `page_one`.